# Is there a difference between meta "keyword" and "keywords"

Tags: html, keyword, meta

I noticed I use `<meta name="keyword"...>` in html. Should I use `name="keywords"` instead of `meta="keyword"` ? I already searched for the difference but couldn't find the solution. In fact, some websites use "keyword".

Answer (score 0):

[You should use "keywords"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-name). I've never seen "keyword" used anywhere.